# Render azure maps route in IoT Central

Tags: javascript, azure-maps, azure-iot-central

I have successfully set up the example available in this Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-your-first-iot-central-app/

When I send the truck to a new customer through a command issued in the IoT central, the device is simulating data and sending telemetry to the IoT central where I can see the current location for the truck. This is visualized through the map available in the dashboard as configured in the tutorial where the marker on the map is updated each time new telemetry is received.

Now I want to make an adjustment to the code so that when a new command is sent to the device, the route to the new coordinates is rendered on the map available in the dashboard. I have seen examples for this where code is added in a .html file (for example this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-route-location). But since I am not using an HTML file for this scenario, how can the route be rendered on the map to be displayed in the IoT central dashboard? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Happy to provide any details/code if necessary.

Best regards,
JWP

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Central uses Azure Maps, but only exposes a small subset of its capabilities. Looking at the documentation for Azure IoT Central, it looks like you can draw a line between points to show a path, but this won't be snapped to the road network: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-location-data#display-device-location